# SQL Server Integration Services process hanging on server

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have built an SSIS package that imports a file, processes it, and generates another file.

I use a flat file source destination, and it correctly rejects rows that fail validation using the "redirect" settings, including when a column is missing in a row. All other rows continue to be processed, and I can log my "error" row in a log file.

This works fine in the developer tools.

When deployed to a server, the package works fine, rejecting rows that have validation errors (eg data type errors) and writing them to my error log.

But when I try to test a file where a row has a missing column, the package just hangs and never completes, and shows no errors.

I have tested this with the same file on my machine in the dev tools, and on the server. The package performs correctly picking up the file, writing the error log, and writing the output file fine on the server for all other scenarios (so I don't believe it is a permissions issue reading/writing to disk)

The flat file connection manager has Format = Delimited, and is otherwise performing correctly as far as I can tell.

[image: Redirect on errors]

Comment: Are there any clues in the SSIS package log?

Comment: None at all. Lots of success messages, no errors anywhere

Comment: So what is the final message when it hangs?

Comment: A "succeed" message for a SQL task that runs a truncate on a table statement. The next task is a Flat File source in a data Data Flow

Comment: Very strange. Normally there is a pre execute but it sounds like that hasn't even started. I can only suggest you turn on verbose logging and see if any more info is written.

Comment: Can you show us how you've set up your record validation checks in SSIS?

Comment: @digital.aaron I've added a screenshot showing each column being redirected if that is what you mean?